# Send audio to server in realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, web-audio-api

I am trying to develop DJ web application. Here i am playing audio using web audio api. I am adding effect to the audio while playing. I want to share this updated audio live to other users. I am planning to use nodejs and socket io.

**How can i send this updated audio to server in realtime?**

Comment: You could try to set up a WebRTC based peer-to-peer connection to your server and then from there stream it to the listeners. But the support for WebRTC is pretty new and older browser versions might not support it

Comment: Or use WebRTC for actual P2P and stream to other users directly. Anyway, I agree that it is a better technology than WebSockets for what you're trying to do. It's not like you care about older browsers since you're using Web Audio anyway.